# Bazel how to use select()with @platforms//os:ios

Tags: bazel

I am compiling on macOS for iOS.

However, when I `select()` on `@platforms//os:ios` it does not work. In the example below, `some_file.cpp` gets compiled when I try to build the `ios_application`.

```
cc_library(
  name = "some-lib",
  src = select({
        "@platforms//os:ios": [],
        "//conditions:default": [
            "some_file.cpp"
        ],
    }),
)

ios_application(
  ...
  deps = ["some-lib"]
)
```

When I `select()` on `@platforms//os:macos` it works. I am really confused how I can `select()` on the target OS and not the host OS.

Comment: I figured it out: rules_apple does not have platforms support yet.